# How to get output in team build in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I started learning TFS Team build. I am having a basic doubt. I referred this 
[article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/vs/define-build). I followed the steps exactly and got succeeded. I created a Console Application and pushed in TFS using TeamServices. My doubt is when we build a Console application in visual studio we will get an exe in bin folder.

1. Same way in this team build how to get the output in my local machine ?
2. What is the difference between the local build using Visual studio and this team build ?

EDIT :

[image]

I added like this. Still I am not able to see the output in the RELEASE folder.

I got the result as success saying

[image]

Still I couldn't figure out the output - the exe produced as a result of build.

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Note : I have a requirement like what you explained in the answer. So why I am using TFS team build. Since I am new I am experimenting with a small example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When to use a build system

Team Build does not replace Visual Studio build. Use Team Build when you have a complex / lengthy build, to easily integrate running unit tests as part of the build or to deploy assemblies to a server after the build is complete.

Most people will setup a TFS build definition to run as "Continous Integration" build, meaning that whenever a commit is checked in, a build occurs. The build would compile and run tests and if it fails all developers can be notified.

### How to get to the build output

When using a build system like TFS build, the build is done on a remote machine. If you want to retrieve the output of the build, add a Publish Build Artifacts step to your build definition. Since the build happened on a remote machine, the remote machine does not have access to your local developer machine.

The artifacts (assemblies) will be available for download on the build summary page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the question now. Please help me